# A little fat man

Tags: riddle, poetry

I'm a little fat man
with a bright red coat
I've a stick in my hand
and a stone in my throat

What am I?

(I am not a gnome of any sort, so please stop posting this!)

This is a pretty big hint so be warned:

> I could be in your garden

Comment: My friend's grandpa taught me this. He's a very nice person.

Comment: Just like the other tags you had :) Looking at the answer below, I was fixated on it being something fantasy-related, so definitely no need for it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pretty sure this is a

> cherry

and the question is a

> real old chestnut.

Comment: Ahahahahaha well done! This riddle indeed is quite old

Answer (score 4):

Are you a

> Gnome?

Reasoning:

I'm a little fat man

> Gnomes are stereotyped as "Little Fat Men"

With a bright red coat

> They usually wear red

I've a stick in my hand

> Probably a shovel?

And a stone in my throat

> Well they are made of Stone

As for the hint:

> Gnomes are found in your garden

Comment: Unfortunately, still no.

Answer (score 1):

> The only thing I can think of is a tomato or tree of the sorts if it's not a gnome.